# tkSimpledialog recording wrong symbol on shifted number keys

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use tkSimpledialog to receive a password as part of a more complicated GUI, however if the offered password includes the symbols that are shifted from the 6, 7, 8, 9, or 0 key then the wrong symbol is recorded on the output from tkSimpledialog. If I do the similar call using getpass.getpass() on the command line, then the correct symbol is recorded.

For note I am using a British keyboard, so the resulting symbols should be:

```
6 - '^'
7 - '&' 
8 - '*'
9 - '('
0 - ')'
```

But instead what I get is:

```
6 - '&'
7 - '*'
8 - '('
9 - ')'
0 - '='
```

So it almost seems like the symbols are moved over one key (this is true in the 6-9 range), however next to the 0 key is "-", and its shifted symbol is "_".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, this issue arose because Tk thought the user was using a German keyboard. The user had set a preference in the Linux system that the default keyboard was German, however the linux cluster ignored this fact and forced the keybinding to be a British keyboard. However Tk seems to consider the preference set within Linux despite python ignoring it, despite getpass.getpass() ignoring it.